# How to formally say "we make this no longer the case"

Tags: expressions

In a document I'm writing there is the following sentence:

> [That problem] has remained only as a theoretical significance since
>   then. In this paper, we show that this is no longer the case.

I would like to specify that "we make this no longer the case" (instead of "we show..."), but this sounds weird to me.

Is there any better way to say that?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: In what sense do you "make" it no longer the case? Do you **assume** that, or do you **demonstrate** it, or do you yourself do something which beyond the scope of the paper, in public reality, **causes** it? Only the last accommodates the use of *make*.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. In the paper, I will present some practical significance of that problem (e.g. solving it can lead to accurate results for [something else], while previously in the literature that problem was presented for analyzing some theoretical results only and no direct solution was given).

Comment: Then say that, instead of creeping up on it: something on the order of "In this paper we demonstrate that [that problem] has significant practical implications."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's effectively "writing advice"

Comment: I don't think there's an elegant way within that framing. So I'd change it to something like "Our work brings practical significance to the problem" or "We demonstrate a practical application of the problem" etc.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. I just wanted a transition sentence before saying what is done in the paper. But I agree with you, that's no necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **substantiate / demonstrate / deduce / prove / evince** that this is no longer the case.

I'd suggest:

Since [that event] the significance of [that problem] has remained purely theoretical. In this paper, we **prove** (or alternative) [that problem] to (have/ be of) practical significance as well.

Comment: Thanks. The modification of the first sentence also sounds better for me.